# Showing geology data from Edina Digimap in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapping, edina

I have downloaded Geology data from [Edina Digimap](https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/geology) and want to view this on QGIS. How do I do this once I have downloaded the geology data from Digimap?

Comment: Please consult the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/index.html) on basic issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop it into QGIS.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to see the layers now but cannot see the geology on the base map?

Comment: Is it the BGS 50k Geology?  If so it's scale restricted, you'll need to zoom in to see it

Comment: It is 50k the coordinate systems match on QGis to EPSG:27700 for the base map and the bedrock layer downloaded from Edina Digimap but still cannot view the geology on the map